# Crash : AES128 encryption in iOS 10 using Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, encryption, aes

I’m using **AES128 encryption**. Below is the code that I’ve used :

```
. . .
let encJson : String = response.objectForKey("data") as! String

let encryptionKey : String = “some key here”

//Crash on this line
response = EncryptionAndConversion.sharedInstance.converEncDataToStringWithAES128(encJson, key: encryptionKey)

print("response : \(response)")
. . .

func converEncDataToStringWithAES128(message:String, key myKey:String) -> NSDictionary {

        let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: message, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

        //The value of result comes nil
        let result = NSString(data: (data?.AES128DecryptedDataWithKey(myKey))!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        return convertStringToDictionary(result!)
    }
```

What might be the reason? I’m getting crash on `converEncDataToStringWithAES128(..)` function with **reason 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I’ve cross-verified that there is no issue with message and key.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Mr.Bista : Nope, issue not resolved.

Comment: what's the print(response.objectForKey("data")) 's output?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but does this also crashes?

```
let encJson : String = response.objectForKey("data") as! String
```

to:

```
guard let encJson = response.objectForKey("data") as? String {
    print("data is not a String")
    return
}
```

Comment: Nope. This dosen't crash out.

Comment: That means the "data" doesn't contains string. what's the `print(response.objectForKey("data"))` 's output?